# Combine 3 mysql queries to form one query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have a school management system that stores student marks and generates student report

**For a student to pass he she has to have ;**

1. An Average of 60% or above
2. Get 60% or above in English Language
3. Get at least 60 % in 5 subjects including English Language

I do have the query to calculate the best 5 subjects and comes up with an average.

**But I need my query to be able to check the value of the passing subject and also does a count of the number of subjects a student has passed (inclusive of English) and presents that info in one query**

```
SELECT student_id, round((SUM(t.mark))/5) average_mark from (
            select marks.student_id,  ROUND(AVG(mark)) as mark  from marks
                INNER JOIN teaching_loads ON teaching_loads.id=marks.teaching_load_id
                INNER JOIN subjects ON subjects.id=teaching_loads.subject_id
            where marks.student_id = "520" AND marks.assessement_id=1  
            GROUP BY subject_id
            order by (subject_id =2) desc, mark desc
            
            LIMIT 5
            
            )t ORDER BY round((SUM(t.mark))/5) DESC
```

How can I build a query that gets checks the value of the passing subject and also does a count of the number of subjects a student has passed (inclusive of English) and presents that info in one query

Something like

Student_id:89
passed_subjects:6
passing_subject_mark:60

In one query I want to be able to get all that data, how can I go about it,
Please help me.

Below is the schema for the databse that stores student data/marks and its related table.

**Marks Table-Stores student marks**

```
CREATE TABLE `marks` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `teacher_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `student_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `teaching_load_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `assessement_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `mark` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

**Teaching Loads**

```
CREATE TABLE `teaching_loads` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `teacher_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `subject_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `class_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `session_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

**Subjects Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `subjects` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `subject_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `subject_type` enum('core','elective','non-value','passing_subject') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

[SQL Fiddle that has the database schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/05c1de)

Answer (score 0):

This is rather tricky because of the last condition.  So, I am thinking window functions:

```
select student_id,
       (case when avg(mark) >= 0.6 then 'Pass'
             when avg(case when subject = 'English' then mark end) > 0.6 then 'Pass'
             when avg(case when seqnum = 5 then mark end) >= 0.6 then 'Pass'
             else 'Fail'
         end) as pass_fail
from (select m.*, subject,
             row_number() over (partition by student_id order by (subject = 'English') desc, mark desc) as seqnum
      from marks m join
           teaching_loads tl
           on tl.id = m.teaching_load_id join
           subjects s
           on s.id = tl.subject_id
     ) ms
group by student_id;
```

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help. I have just run the query, it does work, with the only exception that it shows all students to have passed in the pass_fail column even those that do not meet the criteria. And also, the query's column are only limited to student_id and pass_fail column. In this use case, we need also to show the mark of the passing subject and the number of subjects the student has passed.

Answer (score 0):

can this work?

```
    select student_id,
       (case when avg(mark) >= 0.6 then 'Pass'
         when avg(case when subject = 'English' then mark end) > 0.6 then 'Pass'
         when avg(case when seqnum = 5 then mark end) >= 0.6 then 'Pass'
         else 'Fail'
     end) as pass_fail
       from (select m.*, subject,
         row_number() over (partition by student_id order by (subject = 'English') 
         desc, mark desc) as seqnum
          from marks m join
           teaching_loads tl
             on tl.id = m.teaching_load_id join
                subjects s
                  on s.id = tl.subject_id 
                   join
                    average_mark a
                    on a.student_id = marks.student_id
                    where a.average_mark > 60
            ) ms
   group by student_id;
```